# Gramien operator of controllability!

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, adaptive-control

please I have confusion if someone can help me:
We define the Grammian operator as follows:
\begin{equation}Q_{T}:=L_{T} L_{T}^{*}=\int_{0}^{T} S(T-s) B B^{*} S^{*}(T-s) d s, \quad T>0\end{equation}
when B and S are self-adjoin the expression of  $Q_{T}$ be come:
\begin{equation}Q_{T}:=L_{T} L_{T}^{*}=\int_{0}^{T} |S(T-s) B|^{2}  d s, \quad T>0\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}Q_{T}:=L_{T} L_{T}^{*}=\int_{0}^{T} \big(S(T-s) B\big) \omicron \big(B\,\, S (T-s) \big)d s, \quad T>0\end{equation}
I really don't know !!

also between $ S (T-s) $ and $ B $ is this product or composition?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ and $S$ are self-adjoint then $B^* = B$ and $S^*=S$. If we substitute this into,
\begin{align}
Q_{T}:=L_{T} L_{T}^{*}=\int_{0}^{T} S(T-s) B B^{*} S^{*}(T-s) d s, \quad T>0
\end{align}
you get
\begin{align}
Q_{T}:=L_{T} L_{T}^{*}=\int_{0}^{T} S(T-s) B B S(T-s) d s, \quad T>0
\end{align}

If this is the Controllability Gramian then $S(T-s) = e^{A(T-s)}$ and is a matrix. Therefore, $B S(T-s)$ is the product of two matrices.

Just as a side remark, if you have two linear operators $p$ and $q$ then the composition of these two operators is $p\circ q$. So for an input, $x$, $(p\circ q)(x) = p(q(x))$. However, if the linear operators have a matrix representation, $p(x) = Px$ and $q(x) = Qx$ where $P$ and $Q$ are matrices then the composition of linear operators is the same is the product of two matrices, $(p\circ q)(x) = (PQ)(x)$